# How to model in UML when class has an attribute that realizes an interface

Tags: c#, uml

I have an interface (`MyController`). Two other classes implement that interface (`ControllerTypeA` and `ControllerTypeB`). Another class (`MyFinal`) has a field of `MyController`, so it can contain either `ControllerTypeA` or `ControllerTypeB`. How do I model the relationships between `MyController`, `ControllerTypeA`, `ControllerTypeB`, and `MyFinal` in UML? Here is a working C# program to show what I mean:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScratchApp
{
    public interface MyController
    {
        void method1(String str);
        void method2(int num);
    }

    public class ControllerTypeA : MyController
    {
        public void method1(String str) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is controller type A and the string is: " + str);
        }

        public void method2(int num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is controller type A and the number is: " + num);
        }
    }

    public class ControllerTypeB : MyController
    {
        public void method1(String str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is controller type B and the string is: " + str);
        }

        public void method2(int num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is controller type B and the number is: " + num);
        }
    }

    public class MyFinal
    {
        public MyController myController;

        public MyFinal(MyController mc)
        {
            myController = mc;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MyFinal mf1 = new MyFinal(new ControllerTypeA());
            MyFinal mf2 = new MyFinal(new ControllerTypeB());

            mf1.myController.method1("From mf1");
            mf1.myController.method2(1);
            mf2.myController.method1("From mf2");
            mf2.myController.method2(2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attribute is of type `MyController`, so you have an association here. Both `ControllerType`s realize this `MyController`. Graphically it looks like this:

[image]

As a side note: the attribute `myController` appears twice on the diagram. Mea culpa. It should rather be shown only once: either as role name at the end of the association or as attribute inside `MyFinal` (and then without role name). It's not really wrong this way. But as a matter of style the role name should be preferred here over the attribute in the compartment. This way it's more obvious that it's a distinguished typed attribute.